# sqlite update column with date in python

Tags: python, sqlite

Hi I have a table in sqlite to which I add a column called "Date"

```
add_sql = 'ALTER table ' + table_name +' ADD MyDate text;'
```

I then want to update this column to contain a specific date.

```
update_sql = "update " + table_name + " SET MyDate = '2013-03-12';"
con.execute(add_sql)
con.execute(update_sql)
```

these commands work fine from command line, but not when I execute from my python script.
I get the Date column, but all cells are blank.

Comment: Does invoking `con.commit()` make things work?

Comment: That worked! I wonder why creating the column didn't need the commit, but updating values did.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `sqlite3` module tries to be clever and [commit automatically before some commands, but not before others](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions).

You should call `commit()` whenever needed, or set `isolation_level` to `None`.